# Set texts depending the position of my Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set some text depending of the image position of my Bootstrap carousel. In other words, if the carousel is showing the first image I want to show beside it some illustrative text, if the carousel is showing the second one, it has to show another illustrative text, which corresponds to the number of the image slide.

by now, i have this HTML to set the positions of my carousel and texts:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide col-7 px-0" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active" id="c-1">
                <img class="d-block" src="views\img\banner\boletos.jpg" alt="First slide" style="object-position: center; object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" id="c-2">
                <img class="d-block" src="views\img\banner\concierto.png" alt="Second slide" style="object-position: center; object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" id="c-3">
                <img class="d-block" src="views\img\banner/blog.jpg" alt="Third slide"  style="object-position: top; object-fit: cover; width: 100%; height: 500px;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div><!-- End carousel -->
    <div class="caption-group col-5">
        <div class="carousel-caption active" style="color: #000000!important;" id="t-1">
            <h4><a href="#">tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</a></h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: #000000!important;" id="t-2">
            <h4><a href="#">tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</a></h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption" style="color: #000000!important;" id="t-3">
            <h4><a href="#">tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat</a></h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this css to set some positions:

```
.carousel-caption {
    /*left:0;
    right:0;*/
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);    
    text-align:left;
    padding:15px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0, 0);
    text-shadow:none;
}

.caption-group {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
.list-group-item {
    border-radius:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.list-group-item .active {
    background-color:#eee;  
}

@media (min-width: 992px) { 
    #myCarousel {padding-right:33.3333%;}
    #myCarousel .carousel-controls {display:none;}  
}
@media (max-width: 991px) { 
    .carousel-caption p {display:none;} 
}
```

I think this could be achieved with some Javascript code, but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation for Bootstrap carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-captions), you can insert a `.carousel-caption` element within `.carousel-item` and it will show automatically on larger viewports by default.